# How can you pass a column into a Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a lastrow function that will find the amount of rows in a column.
I want to pass the column as a parameter and return the count.

How do I pass the column?

I tried:

```vb
Function last(X As Variant) As Range
    last = Range(X).End(xlDown).Row
End Function
```

I call the function

```vb
lastrow = last("A:A")
    
'print number to cell
Range("B1").value = lastrow
```

I was getting

> Object Variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your return type of `last`. It should be `Long` rather than `Range`. The bug is because `last` is a Range variable, hence would need to be `Set` rather than just assigned. The following works as you intended:

```
Function last(X As Variant) As Long
    last = Range(X).End(xlDown).Row
End Function
```

A problem with this approach is that it won't work very well if there is any data below a blank line in your column. As an alternative, consider something like:

```
Function last(X As Variant) As Long
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, X).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Called like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow
    lastrow = last("A")
    Range("B1").Value = lastrow
End Sub
```

Note how with this approach, you simply pass the column name as "A" rather than "A:A". Since the type is `Variant`, it would also work when called as `last(1)`.

Comment: nicely explained :)

Comment: `X` in `X As Variant` is not meaningful if the `Function` either expects a column letter or a column number. I guess it would be easy to visualize the argument the function expects if we define it like `Function last(ColLetter_OR_ColNumber As Variant) As Long`. In this case the next line in the function should be changed to `last = Cells(Rows.Count, ColLetter_OR_ColNumber).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @SubodhTiwarisktneer `X` is almost never a meaningful variable name (unless it is being used for the x-coordinate in a mathematical context). `ColLetter_OR_ColNumber` is a bit too long for my taste. Something like `col` would be adequate.

Comment: I agree John! Although `ColLetter_OR_ColNumber` is too long, I would prefer it over 'Col` as it's more descriptive. But that's all about personal preference. :)